# No domain on LAN, local DNS fails

Tags: networking, server, dns

At the moment, I am using a router which has a domain name as part of its settings.  Two days from now, I change ISPs, which means a router with no visible domain name in settings.

In preparation for the change, I blanked the domain name.  Now, the three Ubuntu systems (two server, one GUI, cannot find each other, even though the router's DNS table is unchanged.

i noticed that ping and exportfs both append the domain, e.g. servername.domain.

Is there a way to get the Ubuntu machines to forget about .domain and just look up servername?

Answer (score 0):

Kludged it via Netbios [GitHub: Installing NETBIOS hostname resolution on Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/ngaloppo/322fbd65d82660eb729bcbbecc0bd3d0)

That was after trying lots of other search results.  The router for the new ISP cannot be persuaded to return data from its internal DHCP list.

**Note:** This is practical only if all the Ubuntu machines run Samba.